# Ruby Regex to extract domain from email address

Tags: ruby, regex, email-validation

I have no real previous experience using regex, just saying.
I want to extract domain names from email addresses with the below format.

richardc@mydomain.com
so that the regex returns just: mydomain

With an explanation of how/why it works if possible!
Cheers

Comment: "richardc@mydomain.com".split('@')[1].split('.')[0]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here capturing `(...)` the domain name in group `\1` and replace the whole string with that capture, which yields the domain name only at the end.

```
email = 'richardc@mydomain.com'
domain = email.gsub(/.+@([^.]+).+/, '\1')
# => mydomain
```

`.+` means any character(except `\n`). So its basically matching the whole email string, and capturing the domain name using `([^.]+)` [means anything but dot]

Comment: I added further info. Also, you can use this link http://regex101.com/ to get more explanation of your regex.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to take the parsing route instead, the `mail` gem will do the job:

```
Mail::Address.new("richardc@mydomain.com").domain
```